24.10 problem with NVIDIA
I recently upgraded my PC to Ubuntu 24.10, and I noticed an issue. In my setup, I have several monitors, and I have an NVIDIA 4071 Ti, and it can handle everything I send in its direction. I can play Diablo IV on my primary monitor and have some videos from YouTube on the other.
After the upgrade to 24.10, I've noticed that I cannot do this anymore. When I run Diablo IV, the video on another monitor stops (only the sound continues), and I cannot do anything in that app (usually a browser with YouTube).
What could be this issue? Ubuntu? NVIDIA? How can I solve this?

It looks like starting with XOrg instead of Wayland is the issue.
I still don't know if it's about the new version of Wayland or if it's a problem with the NVIDIA driver. Using them in combination on Ubuntu 24.10, you will have problems.

Perhaps nvidia defaults to Wayland unless you tell it otherwise?
